# Which helicopter in Celerium challenge on Black Ops 2 campaign

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

On the mission "Celerium" on Call of Duty Black Ops 2 there is a challenge that says:

> ELIMATE ENEMY HELI BEFORE LIFT OFF

My question is: What heli? After playing through this mission countless times I can't see what Helicopter it is talking about, could anybody lend a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drone that which Section says "We sure as hell don't want that up in the air" or something similiar. It's almost at the beginning near the controllable drone turret when you first go up the stairs on the right side of the map and then enter the large area.